# renaming files using loop in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a situation here.
I have lot of files like below in linux

```
SIPTV_FIPTV_ID00$line_T20141003195717_C0000001000_FWD148_IPV_001.DATaac
SIPTV_FIPTV_ID00$line_T20141003195717_C0000001000_FWD148_IPV_001.DATaag
```

I want to remove the $line and make a counter from 0001 to 6000 for my 6000 such files in its place.
Also i want to remove the trailer 3 characters after this is done for each file.

After fix file should be like

```
SIPTV_FIPTV_ID0000001_T20141003195717_C0000001000_FWD148_IPV_001.DAT
SIPTV_FIPTV_ID0000002_T20141003195717_C0000001000_FWD148_IPV_001.DAT
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you comfortable with Perl?

Answer (score 0):

With some assumption, I think this should do it: 
1. list of the files is in a file named input.txt, one file per line
2. the code is running in the directory the files are in
3. bash is available

```
awk '{i++;printf "mv \x27"$0"\x27 ";printf "\x27"substr($0,1,16);printf "%05d", i;print substr($0,22,47)"\x27"}' input.txt | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

from the command prompt give the following command

```
% echo *.DAT??? | awk '{
    old=$0;
    sub("\\$line",sprintf("%4.4d",++n));
    sub("...$","");
    print "mv", old, $1}'
%
```

and check the output, if it looks OK

```
% echo *.DAT??? | awk '{
    old=$0;
    sub("\\$line",sprintf("%4.4d",++n));
    sub("...$","");
    print "mv", old, $1}' | sh
%
```

A commentary: `echo *.DAT???` is meant to give as input to awk a list of all the filenames that you want to modify, you may want something more articulated if the example names you gave aren't representative of the whole spectrum... regarding the awk script itself, I used `sprintf` to generate a string with the correct number of zeroes for the replacement of `$line`, the idiom `"\\$..." with two backslashes to quote the dollar sign is required by gawk and does no harm in mawk, and as a last remark I have to say that in similar cases I prefer to make at least a dry run before passing the commands to the shell...